# How to customize header cell in PDF using jsPDF-AutoTable plugin?

Tags: javascript, pdf, pdf-generation, jspdf, html-to-pdf

I encountered strange bug when tried to convert HTML to pdf using **jsPDF-AutoTable** plugin. According to [official Github page](https://github.com/simonbengtsson/jsPDF-AutoTable) there is possibility to customize any headerCell and ordinary cell by using `createdHeaderCell` and `createdCell` hooks. I used the code below to change styling for particular header and row cells (`Name` header and `Jack` cell). I also upload this code [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/6343vevc/).

```
$('#btn').click(function(){

            var columns = ['ID','Name','Address','Age'];
            var rows = [
            [1,'John','Vilnius',22],
            [2,'Jack','Riga',25]
            ];

            var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt');

            doc.setFontSize(20);
            doc.text(30, 30, 'Table'); 

            doc.autoTable(columns, rows, {
                margin: { top: 50, left: 20, right: 20, bottom: 0 },
                createdHeaderCell: function (cell, data) {
                    if (cell.raw === 'Name') {
                        cell.styles.fontSize= 15;
                       cell.styles.textColor = 111;
                    } else {//else rule for drawHeaderCell hook
                        cell.styles.textColor = 255;
                        cell.styles.fontSize = 10;

                    }
                },
                   createdCell: function (cell, data) {
                    if (cell.raw === 'Jack') {
                       cell.styles.fontSize= 15;
                       cell.styles.textColor = 111;
                    } 
                }
            });

            doc.save('output.pdf');
});
```

In this code `createdCell` hook works as expected and style the cell with `Jack`, but nothing happened for `Name` header. Did I miss something or is it a bug?

The funny thing that I find strange workaround using `drawHeaderCell` instead of `createdHeaderCell`, but in this case styling occurs for next `Address` header, not the `Name`as I wanted. My workaround: I used previous `ID` header to style `Name`, but this solution not very beautiful, because I should use `else` rule for styling, otherwise styling will be applied for all headers after `ID`, not just `Name`, so I want to find out what is wrong with my initial code.

Thank you for you attention.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since nobody answered I used my workaround solution using `drawHeaderCell` hook with code like below. I tested it on many tables and it works fine (in production I used dynamically generated table with different headers). The only real drawback that you cannot change color of the 1st header, but hopefully I don't need to do this.

```
$('#btn').click(function(){

            var columns = ['ID','Name','Address','Age'];
            var rows = [
            [1,'John','Vilnius',22],
            [2,'Jack','Riga',25]
            ];

            var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt');

            doc.setFontSize(20);
            doc.text(30, 30, 'Table'); 

            doc.autoTable(columns, rows, {
                margin: { top: 50, left: 20, right: 20, bottom: 0 },
                drawHeaderCell: function (cell, data) {
                    if (cell.raw === 'ID') {//paint.Name header red
                        cell.styles.fontSize= 15;
                       cell.styles.textColor = [255,0,0];
                    } else {
                        cell.styles.textColor = 255;
                        cell.styles.fontSize = 10;

                    }
                },
                   createdCell: function (cell, data) {
                    if (cell.raw === 'Jack') {
                       cell.styles.fontSize= 15;
                       cell.styles.textColor = [255,0,0];
                    } 
                }
            });

            doc.save('output.pdf');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution provided by user2771704 will work well but as said its not change the first header color, for that use "fillColor" as styles.. basically it will change the color for all items and then you can replace the body cell color with "createdCell"

```
    doc.autoTable(columns, rows, {
        createdCell: function (cell, data) {
            cell.styles.fillColor = '#ffffff';
        },

        styles: { fillColor: "#43a047" },
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Version 3 of jsPdf Autotables has replaced `createdCell` with `didParceCell` which provides an object that looks like this:

[image: New <code>didParseCell</code> arguments]

You can then add some code inside this that looks like:

```
        didParseCell: function (table) {

          if (table.section === 'head') {
            table.cell.styles.textColor = '#000000';
          }
       }
```